# Having problems printing each element of an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, loops

I am working on a project and am stuck with what I think is a scope and a logic problem.  I am creating a class called 'Person' with four string variables, last name, first name, favorite color, and gender.  I am creating a second class called 'PersonList' with one variable that is an array of 'Person' objects.  I have set a const int called MAX that determines the size of the array (currently 3).  Ultimately, I would like to enter a the string variables of a 'Person' object into the 'newDude' object declared in the main.  For instance, when the 'readNewPerson' function runs, I enter Doe, John, Blue, Male.  THIS STEP WORKS!!

Next, I would like this 'newDude' to be copied into the 'dudesList' object declared in the main at address dudesList[0] and the 'readNewPerson' function to run again.  If everything works correctly, I am thinking that Smith, Jane, Pink, Female should get copied to dudesList[1] and Johnson, Mike, Green, Male should get copied to dudesList[2].  Finally, I would like to print all three objects to the console.

I am going wrong somewhere in the 'for' loops within the 'addPersonToList' and 'printList' functions where my variable is not iterating properly.  My guess is that since I am declaring the counter 'i' inside the function, it dies and resets to zero every time a 'newDude' is created.  If I'm correct about this, where is the best place to declare the counter and when should I iterate it?

I really appreciate any feedback anyone might be able to offer and I certainly do not want anyone to DO the assignment for me.  I could just use a bit of a push in the right direction at this point as I am incredibly frustrated with what should be a very simple task, at least in concept.

Here is my program so far:

```
// contact list with one-word strings only

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 3;

class Person

{

    private:
        string dudesLName;
        string dudesFName;
        string dudesColor;
        string dudesGender;
    public:
        void readNewPerson (); // function declaration to ask for info
        void printPerson (); //function declaration to display info to console
};

class PersonList

{

    private:
        Person dudesList [MAX];
    public:
        void addPersonToList (Person newDude); //function declaration to add my newDude to the dudesList array
        void printList (); //function declaration to print the entire array

};

//the main function is a simple switch-case asking for user choices

int main (void)

{

Person newDude; //one object contains 4 simple string variables

PersonList List; //one object contains an array of [MAX] dudes

int userChoice; //integer for the user's choice in switch-case

cout << "~~Welcome to Stephen's Contact List~~" << endl;

cout << "Please enter your choice:" << endl;

cout << " 1 - enter " << MAX << " new people" << endl;

cout << " 2 - print the contact list" << endl;

cout << " 3 - retrieve by last name" << endl;

cout << " 4 - retrieve by address" << endl;

cout << " 5 - retrieve by gender" << endl;

cin >> userChoice;

switch (userChoice)

{

    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            {
            newDude.readNewPerson (); //function call to enter one person's info
            List.addPersonToList (newDude); //function call to add newDude to dudesList array
            }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "2 doesn't work yet" << endl;
        List.printList (); //function call to print entire list
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "3 doesn't work yet" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "4 doesn't work yet" << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "5 doesn't work yet" << endl;
        break;
}

cout << "thanks dude!!" << endl;

return 0;
}

// function definitions

void Person::readNewPerson ()

{

    cout << "enter a dude's last name please" << endl;
    cin >> dudesLName;

    cout << "enter a dude's first name please" << endl;
    cin >> dudesFName;

    cout << "enter a dude's favorite color please" << endl;
    cout << "for test purposes, just enter one word" << endl;
    cin >> dudesColor;

    cout << "enter a dude's gender please" << endl;
    cout << "male or female is fine, so is dude or dudette" << endl;
    cin >> dudesGender;

    return;
}

void Person::printPerson ()

{

   cout << "dude's name is " << dudesLName << ", " << dudesFName << endl;

   cout << "his (her?) favorite color is: " << endl;

   cout << dudesColor << endl;

   cout << "and his (her?) gender is: " << endl;

   cout << dudesGender << endl << endl;

   return;

}

void PersonList::addPersonToList (Person newDude)

{

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) //supposed to iterate the array address as it adds Person objects to the array

    dudesList [i] = newDude; //this is where the newDude object is copied to the array

    return;

}

void PersonList::printList()

{

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        dudesList [i].printPerson ();

    return;

}
```

Comment: tl;dr narrow it down so we can help.

Comment: do you want `addPersonToList` to add person to the end? as it stands, it copies to each element

Comment: Using a vector and making your `addPersonToList` use `push_back` seems more logical.

Comment: Karthik, yes.  I would like each newDude object to get copied to the next array index. So, the first guy I enter (Doe, John, Blue, Male) goes to dudesList[0], next guy (Smith, Jane, Pink, Female) goes to dudesList[1], etc. The single newDude object is actually temporary and only serves to collect the personal data. The dudesList array is where I want all my objects stored.

Comment: Chris, vectors are not covered in my lesson. This is an INCREDIBLY simplified version of what the teacher wants. At the end of the day, this is supposed to be a full-fledged contact list with complex string manipulation. I'm just trying to learn some very basic concepts by using one-word strings and a 3 element array.

Comment: hey, u might wanna use the @ symbol to talk to other users, it will send them a notification, like @StephenReeves

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what seems to be going wrong, is that you're adding the same person to the list 3 times. when you call `addPersonToList`

```
void PersonList::addPersonToList (Person newDude)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) //supposed to iterate the array address as it adds Person objects to the array
    dudesList [i] = newDude; //this is where the newDude object is copied to the array
    return;
}
```

now you have a couple of options.

What is probably the easiest to do and to concieve, is to pass the index into your method from where you call it, and make your method like this:

```
void PersonList::addPersonToList (Person newDude, int index)
{
    dudesList [index] = newDude; //this is where the newDude object is copied to the array
}
```

and then in your switch statement, call it like this

```
case 1:
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
        newDude.readNewPerson (); //function call to enter one person's info
        List.addPersonToList (newDude, i); //function call to add newDude to dudesList array
        }
```

Now what is probably the "right" way, is to keep track of what the last index you added was in your PersonList class

```
class PersonList
{
    private:
        Person dudesList [MAX];
        int indexToAdd = 0;  // your new index
    public:
        void addPersonToList (Person newDude); //function declaration to add my newDude to the dudesList array
        void printList (); //function declaration to print the entire array   
};
```

and then incriment that in your `addPersonToList` method

void PersonList::addPersonToList (Person newDude)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) //supposed to iterate the array address as it adds Person objects to the array
    dudesList [indexToAdd] = newDude; //this is where the newDude object is copied to the array
    indexToAdd++;
    return;
}

Comment: Sam I am, thank you, thank you, THANK YOU!!!  Not only does it work great for the addPersonToList, but i was just able to write a VERY simple printing loop to make sure everything prints out to the console properly and i actually get three different values for three different people exactly as i expected!!!

Thanks again for your help!!